# Blank value in Grid with combobox when force select is true

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, extjs5

I got a combocox in editor grid. When entering values I have to validate so I used property **forceSelection : true** . But turning on force selection raise another problem as the combo value is blank when the combo box loss focus as below attached image.

[image: Blank value]

Sample code:

```
var employeeType = [{
    'typeid': 1,
    'typename': 'Contractor'
}, {
    'typeid': 1,
    'typename': 'Regular'
}];

var employeeTypeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['typeid', 'typename'],
    data: employeeType
});

Ext.define('Employees', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'emptype',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        },

    ]
});

var empStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Employees',
    data: [{
        'emptype': 'Regular',
        'name': 'John Doe'
    },{
        'emptype': 'Regular',
        'name': 'Ricky'
    },{
        'emptype': 'Regular',
        'name': 'Mason'
    }]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: empStore,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Employees',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Employee Type',
        dataIndex: 'emptype',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            queryMode: 'local',
            store: employeeTypeStore,
            displayField: 'typename',
            valueField: 'typeid',
            forceSelection : true
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Employee Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'

    }],
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1

    }

});
```

If the value is false then I need to show the last correct value.

Comment: which extjs version ?

Comment: version no 5.1.4

Comment: Once a valid selection is made, there is no way it can get deselected. Am I missing something? So the issue occurs only on first show of the editor when the cell value is empty. If so, why not just select a record in expand? Or set a value in the edit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Expected behavior.

Setting `forceSelection: true` will restrict the user to select the value which is present in the list only. So if you loose the focus without selecting any item it will gonna blank.

You can use `typeAhead: true` to populate and autoselect the remainder of the text being typed if it matches a known value.

Comment: @Tejas thats not an issue thats the expected behaviour.

Comment: if there will be a bug you can prevent it, but its a normal behavior. if you want to modify existing behavior thats a different case which i dont think is really required.